# Epub conversion for a book in Hebrew

Tags: epub

What is the best practice for converting an Indesign file in Hebrew to Epub format?
I have produced two epubs in  Ebglish in the past, but apparently in Hebrew it messes the whole layout up and some of the text is missing...

Comment: Is the complete book in Hebrew or does it contain some Hebrew text? BTW, only a handful of epub**3** apps and readers actually support Hebrew books.
Depending on the bookstore and the target audience of your client it might be easier to create a traditional print book.

Comment: The whole book is in Hebrew. The book is allready printed, but the publisher is interested in publishing an ebook as well. Could a fixed layout epub be a good solution? Many thanks!

Comment: _Could a fixed layout epub be a good solution?_ Creating a fixed layout epub would only be helpful, if the layout of the book is rather complex, e.g., a Hebrew bible or if it's a text book and the page numbers are important. Note that only epub3 apps will support fixed layout books. 
The best format that you can use depends on the bookstore. Your client shouldn't have problems with the iBooks store, but other stores _might_ not fully support RTL books. 
As for your layout issues, you'll have to post html and css snippets and screenshots.

Comment: Thanks :) The publisher would like to upload the ebook to Amazon Kindle and to its own website. I know I have to convert the Epub to Mobi for Kindle, as to the website, I thought to reccomend a specific reader to the user which I know will support the file. Would that work? As to the Layout issues, I will post snippets and screenshots later. I made a test today and found out that layout issues I had with reflowable epub dissapeared when converting to fixed layout..

Answer (score 0):

For the record I wanted to add that the free software KOReader is adding Hebrew and Arabic support. See https://github.com/koreader/koreader/issues/5359